# JavaFX: atualizar um banco de dados inteiro a partir de uma tableView

Tags: banco-de-dados, javafx, uitableview

Boa noite, gente!

Estou construindo um programa em JavaFX, mas ainda sou muito nova nisso.
Então, eu tenho uma tableview com informações sobre estudantes. Essa tableView tem uma coluna "tcbCondicao" (se o pagamento foi ou não quitado) que armazena dados booleanos (a tabela renderiza essas infos como checkBox). Assim, o usuário pode clicar na checkBox quando o aluno paga a mensalidade.

Assim que termina de clicar nas checkBox de todos os alunos que pagaram, o usuário deve clicar no botão "atualizar dados", que deve realizar uma leitura da tabela e atualizar os dados de pagamento no banco de dados.

Eu pesquisei muito, mas apenas encontro o oposto: passar dados do banco de dados para popular a tabela. Como eu posso ler cada um dos itens da minha tabela e passar para o banco de dados de uma vez?

Eu pensei em usar o listview.forEach(item -> ação) para conseguir passar por cada um dos items da tabela, mas não sei como fazer ele pegar as informações do item pelo qual está passando.

Poderiam me ajudar, pleeease!!!

Comment: Está usando JPA ou JDBC? Ajuda também colocar o código do objeto que será persistido e o código do tableview.